# How to set C# version for csi.exe

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, c#-interactive, csi

In C# interactive (as part of Visual Studio 2019 or standalone) I'd like to code something like this using C#:

```
var s = "abcdef";
var s1 = s[2..4];
```

This gives the following message:

> (1,12): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Range' is not defined or
>   imported

Is there a way to modify e.g., csi.exe.config or other means in order to support C# 8.0 ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Update 2020-11-25

It is working in Visual Studio 16.8.2.

Just enter `#reset core` to switch to .NET Core.

---

### Update 2020-07-14

According to https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/45046, it will probably work in the next version of Visual Studio 2019.

> Adds a new option to `#reset` command that allows the user to switch Interactive Window host to .NET Core:
>
> - `#reset 32` - switches to .NET Framework 32-bit process
> - `#reset 64` - switches to .NET Framework 64-bit process
> - **`#reset core` - switches to .NET Core 64-bit process**
>
> Leaves the default to .NET Framework 64-bit for now.

---

### Original answer

It looks like there is no way currently. Because C# Interactive is not able to run Core CLR.

> The Interactive Window only supports .NET Framework at this point.
> Hence features are limited to C# 7.3 and lower. Too enable C# 8 we
> would need to first enable running on Core CLR (see #4788).

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/40341

Comment: the #reset option appears to be available in Visual Studio tool only, not when you execute csi.exe from command line

Comment: **Please vote!!!**
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-interactive-doesnt-use-the-newest-la/10346230

Answer (score -2):

Looks like dotnet interactive provides similar functionality through Jupyter Notebooks.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-interactive-preview-3-vs-code-insiders-and-polyglot-notebooks/
That saved my day :-)